# Easies way to embed Flash

Tags: html, flash

First of all I want to clarify that I know how to embed a swf file on a site. What I am asking is something a little different. To understand, I will elaborate.

I am working on a small "widget" that I want to allow site owners to embed on their e websites. This widget will show some info depending on different parameters (mainly an ID). This data will be retrieved from a database that I host and is on different server than the site(s) that have this widget embedded. I know flash can communicate with PHP to send an retrieve data, so this I don't expect to be a problem. The website owners that will want this widget will get an "embed code" from me that will have the ID, probably the width and height and other info. They will not host the swf file however.

What I want to know is what you think would be the best way to have this code in order for it to be as small as possible and with little invasion. I know that these widgets are usually made with javascript where the user only needs a `<script type="text/javascript" src="...?id=111412"></script>`, but since I don't know advanced Javascript to make the widget in it, I made it in Flash.

Also, I would need to have update control, so that if I change the SWF file, the new version will appear on all the websites that have it embedded.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not reading all this, if you want to embed a flash file use the `<object>` tag

Comment: Using the "object" tag will make a long embed code. Like I said, I want to offer the users a more easy way of doing it, with a code as small as possible.

Comment: You could host an iframe the way YouTube does.

Comment: An iFrame won't do, since I will need to have a different iFrame for each ID and size combination. Maybe not the size, since I can make the SWF fill the entire space, but still.